# How to point AWS EC2 to Domain name server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, dns-hosting

I have amazon free tier ec2 account. Have deployed my java EE application into apache tomcat installed in AWS.
I have created new elastic IP and associated with the public DNS of the AWS. 
Now I can hit the IP address with 8080 port in browser and I could able to see the application which I have deployed (example: XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/login.jsp).

I have purchased one DNS in square brothers(Example: www.think.com). 
now I want to access the application with the DNS which I have purchased, not with the elastic IP address.(Example www.think.com/login.jsp) Can any one please let me know how to point to DNS to elastic IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use your own domain you need to setup a so called `Hosted Zone` in Route53 (which is an AWS service). You should then create a `Record Set` which you point against your obtained `Elastic IP`.

Read more about it here (see step 3): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewDNS.html

If the link above does not give you all the answers, try searching the web for `aws route53 dns tutorial` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked fine using Hosted zones in route s3...

Now i want to access the application through the domain name. Example www.example.com/login.jsp
For the same i have placed my web app in ROOT folder of the apache tomcat in AWS, and i can access the app.
But i want to deploy the war file and access the application. If i put the war file in ROOT folder i am not able to access the application.
Cab you please help me out on this like where to put the war file in apache tomcat folder in AWS

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you! Well, getting your application up and running is a completely other matter. Unfortunately I have very little experience in Tomcat and will not be able to help you with that, this is probably not the right forum for that either. Try a web search for something like `tomcat deploy war file`.